# How to extract files from a .box file using the command line?

Tags: linux

I have downloaded a `.box` file but I do not know how to extract the data in it. I look it up on Google but did not find anything. Do you know how to do that using command line?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/format.html) box files are just tar, tar.gz or zip files.  You should, therefore, be able to use `tar -xf` or `unzip` on it.